# How can I speed up Window Animation scale?

Tags: settings

I have a Samsung Galaxy S4 running Android 4.4.2. It's fast but I'm a heavy user and I'd like to make it a bit faster. How can I speed up Window Animation scale?

Answer (score 2):

I found that by tweaking the following settings, the overall performance of my phone had increased.

> Go to Settings > Developer Options

Scroll down to `Window animation scale` and change the value from 1X to .5x (if you want faster performance you can turn this setting off).

Do the same for `Transition animation scale` and `Animator animation scale`.

In order to reach these settings you must have access to `Developer Options`.

> On Android 4.2 and newer, Developer Options are hidden by default. To
>   access them, go to `Settings` > `About phone` and tap `Build number`
>   7 times. Return to the previous screen to find Developer options.

Comment: +1. Just a side note, on certain Samsung firmwares on the S4 this defaults back to 1x when you reboot the phone. Just a little bug that Samsung haven't fixed! Oh and Custom Launchers can have their own speeds and scales set too, they've just added an Android L style animation for app opening and it's very nice!

Comment: Nice! Is it publicly available?

Comment: I'm not sure as I signed up for the Beta, check Nova Launcher on the Play store and you'll see if the "What's New" mentions the Android L animation etc!

Comment: @RossC  I currently use Nova Launcher Prime. I love it.

Comment: @Dark_Cyber Nova can override the animation speed on its own. Go to Nova Settings -> Look and feel.  Scroll Speed and Animation Speed will give you options for speeding up these animations.